# JavaScript OOP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have object `myObject`, inside I have function `execute()`, inside I have `$.ajax({` which have `complete: function(xmlHttp){`. Inside that function I want to call setResult which is defined in the `myObject`. How to do that?

```
function myObject() {
    this.setResult = setResult;
    function setResult(result) {
        this.result = result;   
    }

    function execute() {
         $.ajax({
            complete: function(xmlHttp){
                (?) setResult(jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttp.responseText));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to do OOP is to use `myObject` as a constructor, and extend its `prototype` object with whatever needs to be inherited.

```
function myObject() {
    // constructor function
}

myObject.prototype.setResult = function (result) {
    this.result = result;   
}

myObject.prototype.execute = function() {
     $.ajax({
        context: this, // bind the calling context of the callback to "this"
        complete: function(xmlHttp){
            this.setResult(jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttp.responseText));
        }
    });
}

var obj = new myObject();
obj.execute();
```

There's no *requirement* that it be done this way, but it's very common.

You need to keep in mind that the calling context of a function varies based on how that function is called.  With respect to the `complete:` callback, jQuery sets the context, so it won't be your object unless you tell jQuery to make it that object *or use some other way to bind the context*.

jQuery's `$.ajax` method gives you a `context:` property that lets you set the calling context of the callbacks, as I've shown above.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myObject() {
    var that = this; // Reference to this stored in "that"
    this.setResult = setResult;

    function setResult(result) {
        this.result = result;   
    };

    function execute() {
         $.ajax({
            complete: function(xmlHttp){
                that.setResult(jQuery.parseJSON(xmlHttp.responseText));
        }
    });
}
```

Also you can check out jquery proxy and/or bind